# Como dar color al texto que añado a una imagen con sharp-npm en node.js

Tags: nodejs, npm

Estoy procesando imágenes con sharp-npm en node.js, y además les añado texto. El problema es que no consigo darle color al texto que añado con sharp. He probado todo lo que he encontrado en la documentación, pero solo consigo dar color a las imágenes. Lo único que he conseguido con el texto es dejar el fondo translúcido con un boolean. Conozco otros modos de arreglar este problema, pero me gustaría poder hacerlo con sharp si existe la fórmula.
Muchas gracias de antemano. Os dejo una muestra del código.

```
const fs = require("fs").promises;
const path = require("path");
const sharp = require("sharp");

const imagen = process.argv[2];

async function existeLaImagen(imagen) {
  try {
    await fs.access(imagen);

    const extValidas = [".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png", ".webp"];
    if (!extValidas.includes(path.extname(imagen))) {
      throw new Error(
        "El argumento no es una imagen o no contiene la extensión correcta"
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

async function existeDirectorio(directorio) {
  try {
    await fs.access(directorio);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

async function carpetaConVariaciones(imagen) {
  try {
    await existeLaImagen(imagen);

    const directorio = path.join(__dirname, "imagenes");

    if (!(await existeDirectorio(directorio))) {
      await fs.mkdir(directorio);
    }

    const colocarTextoColor = sharp(imagen)
      .composite([
        {
          input: {
            text: {
              text: "hola que tal estas",
              width: 1500,
              height: 200,
              rgba: true,
            },
          },
          top: 1500,
          left: 500,
        },
      ])
      .tint({ r: 255, g: 255, b: 0 });
    colocarTextoColor.toFile(path.join(directorio, "conTextoColor.jpg"));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
}
carpetaConVariaciones(imagen);
```

Espero haberme explicado bien :)

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta estaba en añadir el css en el mismo 'text'

```
    const colocarTextoColor = sharp(imagen).composite([
      {
        input: {
          text: {
            text: '<span foreground="red">hola que </span><span background="cyan">tal estas</span>',
            width: 1500,
            height: 200,
            rgba: true,
          },
        },
        top: 1500,
        left: 500,
      },
    ]);
```